# Uncertainty propagation formula in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, uncertainty

I'm trying to write a short piece of code that will perform propagation of errors. So far, I can get Mathematica to generate the formula for the error delta_f in a function f(x1,x2,...,xi,...,xn) with errors dx1,dx2,...,dxi,...dxn:

```
fError[f_, xi__, dxi__] := 
  Sum[(D[f[xi], xi[[i]]]*dxi[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[xi]}]^(1/2)
```

where fError requires that the input function f has all of its variables surrounded by {...}. For example,

```
d[{mv_, Mv_, Av_}] := 10^(1/5 (mv - Mv + 5 - Av))
FullSimplify[fError[d, {mv, Mv, Av}, {dmv, dMv, dAv}]]
```

returns

```
2 Sqrt[10^(-(2/5) (Av - mv + Mv)) (dAv^2 + dmv^2 + dMv^2)] Log[10]
```

My question is, how can I evaluate this? Ideally I would like to modify fError to something like:

```
fError[f_, xi__, nxi__, dxi__]
```

where nxi is the list of actual values of xi (separated since setting the xi's to their numerical values will destroy the differentiation step above.) This function should find the general formula for the error delta_f *and then* evaluate it numerically, if possible. I think the solution should be as simple as a Hold[] or With[] or something like that, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19395/52) may prove useful.

Comment: @rcollyer Those all seem a little more advanced than what I need. I'm really just looking for an elegant, one- or two-line solution that I can adapt to various calculations. I never have to deal with correlated errors, either. I have found, though, that if I just call fError[f,xi,dxi]/.{x1->nx1,...}, it works. That's good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not following everything that you've done, and since this was posted two years ago it's likely you aren't working on it anymore anyways. I'll give you my solution for error propagation in hopes that it will somehow help you or others.

I tried to include the best documentation that I could in the video and files linked below. If you open the .cdf file and weed through it you should be able to see my code...

Files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKVw6gFYxk_YUk4a25ZRFpKaU0/view?pli=1

Video Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1aM_oSIN7w

-Brian

**Edit:**
I posted the links because I couldn't attach files and didn't want to post code with no documentation for people new to mathematica. Here's the code directly. I would encourage anyone finding this solution helpful to take a quick look at the documentation because it demonstrates some tricks to improve productivity.

```
Manipulate[
 varlist = ToExpression[variables];
 funct = ToExpression[function];
 errorFunction[variables, function]
 , {variables, "{M,m}"}, {function, "g*(M-m)/(M+m)"}, 
 DisplayAllSteps -> True, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17}, 
 AutoAction -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   errorFunction[v_, f_] := (
     varlist = ToExpression[v];
     funct = ToExpression[f];
     varlength = Length[Variables[varlist]];
     theoretical = 
      Sqrt[(Total[
         Table[(D[funct, Part[varlist, n]]*
             Subscript[U, Part[varlist, n]])^2, {n, 1, 
           varlength}]])];
     Part[theoretical, 1];
     varlist;
     uncert = Table[Subscript[U, Part[varlist, n]], {n, 1, varlength}];
     uncert = DeleteCases[uncert, Alternatives @@ {0}];
     theoretical = Simplify[theoretical];
     Column[{Row[{Grid[{
           {"Variables", varlist},
           {"Uncertainties", uncert},
           {"Function", function},
           {"Uncertainty Function", theoretical}}, Alignment -> Left, 
          Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
          ItemStyle -> {"Text", FontSize -> 20}, 
          Background -> {{LightGray, None}}]}],
       Row[{
         Grid[{{"Brian Gennow  March/24/2015"}}, Alignment -> Left, 
          Spacings -> {2, 1}, ItemStyle -> "Text", 
          Background -> {{None}}]
         }]}]))]
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change (even though its yours)

Comment: it would be nice if you could extend this code to correlated variables

Answer (score 1):

This question was posted over 5 years ago, but I ran into the same issue recently and thought I'd share my solution (for uncorrelated errors).

I define a function `errorProp` that takes two arguments, `func` and `vars`. The first argument of `errorProp`, `func`, is the symbolic form of the expression for which you wish to calculate the error of its value due to the errors of its arguments. The second argument for `errorProp` should be a list of the form

```
{{x1,x1 value, dx1, dx1 value},{x2,x2 value, dx2, dx2 value}, ... , 
{xn,xn value, dxn, dxn value}}
```

Where the `xi`'s and `dxi`'s are the symbolic representations of the variables and their errors, while the `xi value` and `dxi value` are the numerical values of the variable and its uncertainty (see below for an example).

The function `errorProp` returns the symbolic form of the error, the value of the input function `func`, and the value of the error of `func` calculated from the inputs in `vars`. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[errorProp];
errorProp[func_, vars_] := Module[{derivs=Table[0,{Length[vars]}], 
funcErrorForm,funcEval,funcErrorEval,rplcVals,rplcErrors},

For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[vars], ii++,
    derivs[[ii]] = D[func, vars[[ii, 1]]];
];

funcErrorForm = Sqrt[Sum[(derivs[[ii]]*vars[[ii, 3]])^2,{ii,Length[vars]}]];

SetAttributes[rplcVals, Listable];
rplcVals = Table[Evaluate[vars[[ii, 1]]] :> Evaluate[vars[[ii, 2]]], {ii, 
Length[vars]}];

SetAttributes[rplcErrors, Listable];
rplcErrors = Table[Evaluate[vars[[ii, 3]]] :> Evaluate[vars[[ii, 4]]], {ii, 
 Length[vars]}];

funcEval = func /. rplcVals;
funcErrorEval = funcErrorForm /. rplcVals /. rplcErrors;
Return[{funcErrorForm, funcEval, funcErrorEval}];
];
```

Here I show an example of `errorProp` in action with a reasonably complicated function of two variables:

```
ClearAll[test];
test = Exp[Sqrt[1/y] - x/y];
errorProp[test, {{x, 0.3, dx, 0.005}, {y, 0.9, dy, 0.1}}]
```

returns

```
 {Sqrt[dy^2 E^(2 Sqrt[1/y] - (2 x)/y) (-(1/2) (1/y)^(3/2) + x/y^2)^2 + (
 dx^2 E^(2 Sqrt[1/y] - (2 x)/y))/y^2], 2.05599, 0.0457029}
```

Calculating using the error propagation formula returns the same result:

```
{Sqrt[(D[test, x]*dx)^2 + (D[test, y]*dy)^2], 
test /. {x :> 0.3, dx :> 0.005, y :> 0.9, dy :> 0.1}, 
Sqrt[(D[test, x]*dx)^2 + (D[test, y]*dy)^2] /. {x :> 0.3, 
dx :> 0.005, y :> 0.9, dy :> 0.1}}
```

returns

```
{Sqrt[dy^2 E^(
2 Sqrt[1/y] - (2 x)/y) (-(1/2) (1/y)^(3/2) + x/y^2)^2 + (
dx^2 E^(2 Sqrt[1/y] - (2 x)/y))/y^2], 2.05599, 0.0457029}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 12 introduced the [Around](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) function that handles error propagation using the differential method.

So although not quite in the format required in the question, but something like this is possible:

```
expression = a^2*b;
expression /. {a -> Around[aval, da], b -> Around[bval, db]}
```

output:

```
aval^2 bval ± Sqrt[aval^4 db^2+4 bval^2 Abs[aval da]^2]
```

Instead of *aval, bval, da, db* you can use numerical values as well.